# What's the name of the sound that a hungry stomach makes?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When the stomach makes a sound like croaking of a frog or similar to it (mine just did, it's trying to speak to me), that alert when you are hungry, is there a name for it?

I mean the name for this very sound?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a term for that in English. It's called [**a growl**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/growl):

> Why is my stomach **growling**, but I'm not hungry?
>
> I can hear my stomach **growling**. I'm gonna go grab a bite.

There are actually a number of terms in English that are used to describe abdominal sounds (sometimes called bowel sounds) among which are words like **gurgle**, **grumble**, **rumble** et cetera, but **growl** is by far the most common. Here's another example straight from [**Oxford English Living Dictionaries (OELD)**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gurgle):

> My stomach **gurgled**.

Comment: The sound itself is called "**a gurgle**" right?

Comment: Yep. A gurgle, a growl, a meow, etc. That's how you can refer to an instance of uttering a sound of any kind.

Comment: If you want to be really fancy, you can call it a _borborygmus_.

Comment: _borborygmus_ seems like an appropriate answer on English Language & Usage (where odd trivia is more relevant), but here I think it's more useful to focus on the common rather than scientific terms - I certainly have never heard that word, as a native speaker!

Comment: From your answer, I see there is more than one term for this physiological act. How would I know if "growling" is more common than "rumble" or "rumbling"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tummy+rumbled%2Ctummy+rumbling%2Ctummy+growled%2Ctummy+growling%2Cgrowling+tummy&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctummy%20rumbled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20rumbling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20growled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20growling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrowling%20tummy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctummy%20rumbled%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20rumbling%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20growled%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ctummy%20growling%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrowling%20tummy%3B%2Cc1

Comment: @Mari-LouA However if you use "stomach" instead of "tummy" you get the complete reverse (and not to mention that "stomach growled" completely overshadows any "tummy" use). The exact phrasing makes a large difference in this case, regarding what's more common - it's a lot harder to pinpoint what a good suggested use is.

Comment: @Bilkokuya it's yet again the AmEng and BrEng divide https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomach+rumbled%2Cstomach+rumbling%2Cstomach+growled%2Cstomach+growling%2Cgrowling+tummy&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstomach%20rumbled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstomach%20rumbling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstomach%20growled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstomach%20growling%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the mid-1990s in the British English corpus citations for stomach growled/growling comes from American authors and magazines.

Comment: @CookieMonster I would swap the order, place "growl" above the rest, and place "gurgle" last.

Comment: There's probably quite a bit of regional variation - as a UK speaker, I'd use "*rumble*" by default, and the other terms ("*gurgle*", "*growl*", etc) when I had a more specific nuance to convey.

Comment: for hunger, growl or rumble. Gurgling is really a throat thing not a stomach thing.

Answer (score 5):

In medical speak, they use a delightful little word called **borborygmi**, which is the rumbling or gurgling noise made by the movement of fluid and gas in the intestines. That said, it would be unlikely to be used in casual conversation.

Personally, I would say:

> My stomach is **rumbling**

Or even

> My stomach is **talking**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a stomach **growl**, it can be also referred as a stomach **moan**. Or it could be a stomach **drone**.

(*Droning* is making a deep, low-pitched humming noise, discontinuously.)

Answer (score 0):

In my locale of southern England, the term is "my stomach is **rumbling**".

Other locales use different terms.